# Fourier Transform and Music Analysis

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, music, derivation

I am a senior in high-school and am currently trying to conduct an exploration on Fourier Analysis, specifically using the Discrete Fourier Transform to analyze a chord played on my piano. Basically, I'd play a chord of 3 notes, deduce the different frequencies of the sound wave, and estimate the chord played. I am having issues trying to come up with theory to the Fourier Transform, including related math concepts, derivation of the formula, and key math that needs to be understood in order to use the Fourier transform. Is there any way someone could help with that as I am a bit unfamiliar to this. Thanks.

Comment: So you might need to consider the harmonics of the 3 different notes.  Because what you'll see in a basic Fourier spectrogram will be frequency components of every harmonic of the 3 notes.  So, if you're trying to identify your 3 notes, you have a lotta information to sift through.  Note separation or even polyphonic pitch detection is kinda a hard problem.